# Recreate crossDissolve navigation in Flutter

Tags: animation, routes, navigation, flutter

How can i recreate the `modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve` from iOS when navigating between two pages in Flutter using a Route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have, you can change the transitionDuration :

```
              Navigator.of(context).push(
        PageRouteBuilder<Null>(
            pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
                Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
              return AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: animation,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                    return Opacity(
                      opacity: animation.value,
                      child: YourWidgetPage(),
                    );
                  });
            },
            transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600)),
      );
```